# Inserir nodo numa árvore binária

Tags: c, algoritmo, ponteiro, memória, árvore-binária

Como inserir um nodo em uma árvore binária? Sempre dá erro de segmentação quando o código entra em `if (arv == NULL)`

```
struct no {
  int info;
  struct no *esq;
  struct no *dir;
};


 typedef struct no node;


 struct  node *insere (node *arv, int valor) {

if (arv == NULL) {   //aqui esta o erro

   node p = malloc(sizeof(node));
   p.info = valor;
   p.esq = NULL;
   p.dir = NULL;
   *arv = p;

    return arv;
}
else if (valor > arv->info) {
    arv->dir = insere(arv->dir, valor);
    return arv->dir;
}
else {
        arv->esq = insere(arv->esq, valor);
return arv->esq;
}

 void imprime (node *arv) { 

if (arv != NULL) {

    imprime(arv->esq);
    printf("\n %d", arv->info);
    imprime(arv->dir);
}

}

int main (void) {

  node *arv;
  arv->info = 1;
  arv->dir = NULL;
  arv->esq = NULL;

  insere(arv, 2);
  insere(arv, 3);

  imprime(arv);
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código nem compila, está bem desorganizado e tem algumas falhas. Eu resolvi alocando memória inicial para a árvore, o que causava o erro descrito, e depois havia mais algumas confusões na alocação dos nós. Ainda há erros no algoritmo, mas já foi dado um passo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct no {
    int info;
    struct no *esq;
    struct no *dir;
} Node;

Node *insere(Node *arv, int valor) {
    if (arv == NULL) {
        arv = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        arv->info = valor;
        arv->esq = NULL;
        arv->dir = NULL;
        return arv;
    } else if (valor > arv->info) {
        arv->dir = insere(arv->dir, valor);
        return arv->dir;
    } else {
        arv->esq = insere(arv->esq, valor);
        return arv->esq;
    }
}

void imprime (Node *arv) { 
    if (arv != NULL) {
        imprime(arv->esq);
        printf("\n %d", arv->info);
        imprime(arv->dir);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    Node *arv = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    arv->info = 1;
    arv->dir = NULL;
    arv->esq = NULL;
    insere(arv, 2);
    insere(arv, 3);
    imprime(arv);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iNISoH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jfeakkqk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/BinaryTree.c).